# Ubuntu phone: basics questions

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'd like to buy an UbuntuPhone, but, before, I need to get a bit of knowledge more about it.
On my Android phone, now, for job emergency reasons, I'm using a VPN app (GlobalProtect by Palo Alto Networks), a terminal emulator that supports ssh and mostly I need to connect to an enterprise wi-fi in PEAP/GTC.

So, my questions are:

- does UbuntuPhone support vpnc as Ubuntu desktop/server does?
- is UbuntuPhone provided by sort of gnome-terminal and ssh as as Ubuntu desktop/server is?
- does UbuntuPhone supplicant support PEAP/GTC as Ubuntu desktop/server does?

Thanks and cheers,

Silvia

Answer (score 1):

VPN is supported since OTA10 update, which has been released just yesterday, but I have nerve uused it.

The is a Terminal App and its no problem to use ssh in the terminal app. But X-Session forwarding with  the -X option will not work because Ubuntu Touch uses Mir as Displayserver.

PEAP and enterprise Wini is supported, you can activate it manually durobg wife setup.

If you have trouble during setup or further questions, feel free to contact me.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for being so late. 
I don't need to forward x session: it's already painful managing a ldap server while in vacations and by the means of a mobile phone 4g connected! So, maybe, I'll buy ubuntuphone.